# Ruby: Ranges or Sequences?

Tags: ruby, range, sequence

I have a question about ruby ranges:

```
rng = (1..10)
rng.include? 2.17 # => true (rng it's a real range)
rng.each { |num| puts num } # => prints integers between 0 and 11 (rng it's sequences)
```

What are ranges in Ruby? Sequences or real Ranges? 
What I mean of real Ranges: Every numbers between two numbers.

Comment: I suppose you could think of finite ranges as sequences, but I don't think that's helpful, and infinite ranges, such as `1.0..2.0` are certainly not sequences (though there exist sequences that include every number between `1.0` and `2.0`). Do you mean "*real* ranges" as opposed to, say, "phantom ranges? You need to give more thought to your last two sentences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The confusion stems from the fact that Ruby has two types of ranges, which are treated somewhat differently: *numeric ranges*, having numeric objects as endpoints, and *non-numeric ranges*, having non-numeric objects as endpoints.

The doc for [Range#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) states, "Returns `true` if obj is an element of the range, `false` otherwise. If begin and end are numeric, comparison is done according to the magnitude of the values.". Therefore,

```
(1..10).include? 2.17 #=> true
```

does not mean that `2.17` is an element of the range, merely that `2.17.between?(1, 10) #=> true`.

You have a point that the first sentence of the doc is inaccurate--or at best misleading--for numeric ranges. After all, if we write

```
(1..10).any? { |n| n == 2.17 } #=> false
```

what does it mean that `2.17` is "an element of the range"? That is not an issue for non-numeric ranges.

I think the doc for `Range#include?` should be more precise. Firstly, after having earlier defined *numeric* and *non-numeric* ranges, it would be helpful to define the concept of a *member* or *element* of a non-numeric range: "For a non-numeric range `r`, `obj` is a member of `r` if and only if `r.any? { |o| o == obj } #=> true`. I see no reason to attempt a definition of *member* for numeric ranges.

`Range#include?` might then be documented as follows: "A numeric range `r` returns `true` if `r.begin <= obj <= r.end` for two-dot ranges and `r.begin <= obj < r.end` for three-dot ranges; else returns `false`. A non-numeric range returns `true` if `obj` is a member of the range; else `false`."

Comment: Numeric Ranges sometimes behave like sequences; quite smart sequences: `(50..1000000000).sum` returns instantly, I guess because it is a ArithmeticSequence